# Allowed App file locations - with-or-without Sandboxing

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

OK, my question is straightforward but I definitely cannot find one straightforward answer. So, I'd be glad if you could help.

**What I want :**

A place (either on 10.6 - without sandboxing - or 10.7-and-later, WITH sandboxing) where my app can freely write some data.

**In a few words :**

- I want to know if there's any system function (e.g. `NSHomeDirectory()`) which points to a safe location for me to write to (OS X version shouldn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here I am, answering my own question.

So, what if we just need access to the **Application Support** directory (and create it if it doesn't exist), no matter if we're on 10.6 (without sandboxing enabled) or 10.7+?

Here's the **universal** solution *(I myself wrote a category on `NSFileManager` for that, but even a simple function or macro could do...)* :

**Interface :**

```
// NSFileManager+Paths.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSFileManager (Paths)

+ (NSString*)applicationSupportDirectory;

@end
```

**Implementation :**

```
// NSFileManager+Paths.m

#import "NSFileManager+Paths.h"

@implementation NSFileManager (Paths)

+ (NSString*)applicationSupportDirectory
{
    NSError *error;
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error] path];
}

@end
```

Rather simple, huh?

---

**HINT :** Please have a look at the 2 comments below for a *fix* to this answer for a more elegant solution.

Comment: There is a problem here, which is that you are exactly right: This returns the path to the Application Support directory. When you are sandboxed, that's not much of a problem, but when you aren't, depositing random files directly into ~/Library/Application Support is rude. You should create a directory within Application Support and return the path to that directory. Better to do that here than at every place in your code where you need to access something in your folder within Application Support.

Comment: @PeterHosey Yep, you're right. And, that's exactly what I ended up doing : append a fixed path component (my bundle id : `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]`). And hopefully, we're safe this way...